# Is "uncomplete" a word?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, negation, prefixes, is-it-a-word

Or would I just use *incomplete*?  Would there be any instance that one would uncomplete?

Comment: Some dictionaries list this as a [synonym of incomplete](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Uncomplete); others do not, but do list [uncompleted](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uncompleted?region=us). Both are adjectives.

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40870/antonym-of-the-verb-complete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word which means *not complete* is **incomplete**.

Although http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ defines uncomplete (adj) as not yet finished:
 **Ex: an uncompleted play** .

the use of uncomplete as an adjective is very rare. I would suggest you to use **incomplete** or **unfinished**.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a verb, that's why he tried *uncomplete*, as in *uninstall* or *unstar*.

Comment: @RiMMER: Presumably this hypothetical verb *uncomplete* would mean something like *"to start, but not finish [something]"*. We don't have a verb *unfinish* either, but we do have what looks like a present participle *unending* for another of these "non-verbs". And of course there is precedent - no-one would dispute that *undelete* is now a valid verb.

Answer (score 2):

The correct adjective is **incomplete**. The verb "uncomplete" does not exist. If you want to express that someone took something that had been complete and made it incomplete, you would have to say:

> He **removed** the cog wheel from the engine, **rendering it incomplete**.

or

> She **erased** her last answer (and now her application form is incomplete).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a word, but it is uncommon. Less rare is the adjective "Uncompleted".